# How to add next,prev and rotate in image gallery in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Actually I am very new to ReactJS Here I am trying to access the previous and next image when I click on prev or next button respectively but I am not able to get the   previous image as I doesn't able to know the value of this.state.url

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            showModal: false,
            pointer: 0,
            url: ""
          };

          this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
          this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
          this.nextClick = this.nextClick.bind(this);
          this.prevClick = this.prevClick.bind(this);
        }

        render() {
          return (            
            <div
              refs="gallery-container"
              className="container-fluid gallery-container"
            >
              <div className="row">
                {imgUrls.map((url, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index} className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xl-2">
                      <div className="gallery-card">
                        <GalleryImage
                          key={index}
                          className="gallery-thumbnail"
                          src={url}
                          alt={"Image number " + (index + 1)}
                        />

                        <span
                          className="card-icon-open fa fa-expand"
                          value={url}
                          onClick={e => this.openModal(url, e)}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>

              <GalleryModal
                isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                onClick={this.closeModal}
                onNext={this.nextClick}
                onPrev={this.prevClick}
                src={this.state.url}
              />
            </div>
          );
        }

        // Function for opening modal dialog
        openModal(url, e) {
          this.setState({
            showModal: true,
            url: url
          });
        }

        // Function for closing modal dialog
        closeModal() {
          this.setState({
            showModal: false,
            url: ""
          });
        }
        nextClick() {
          alert(this.state.url);
          alert("next");
        }
        prevClick() {
          alert(this.state.url);
          alert("prev");
        }
      }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/86vk5y1L/1/)

I am trying to add [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/tk2e4du8/1/) logic which I created, into the above code but I am stuck and confused how can I merged into my above code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your demo I created a working variant with prev & next buttons:
https://jsfiddle.net/qjgka47z/4/

So, the main elements that were missing you can find in the nextClick & prevClick actions:

```
nextClick() {
  const { pointer } = this.state;
  const imgLength = imgUrls.length;
  const newPointer = pointer === imgLength - 1 ? 0 : pointer + 1;
  this.setState({ pointer: newPointer });
}

prevClick() {
  const { pointer } = this.state;
  const imgLength = imgUrls.length;
  const newPointer = pointer === 0 ? imgLength - 1 : pointer - 1;
  this.setState({ pointer: newPointer });
}
```

Basically, I did the same that you did in your logic: I calculated the position of the next/prev image based on the length of the image array you provided and the current selected image.
When we now click on next/prev we set the new pointer of the selected image in state and in the GalleryModal component we just show the image of the curernt position in the image array (this way, there is no need to save the url in state):

```
<GalleryModal
  isOpen={this.state.showModal}
  onClick={this.closeModal}
  onNext={this.nextClick}
  onPrev={this.prevClick}
  src={imgUrls[this.state.pointer]}
/>
```

Comment: Actually I just notice when I click on any image a warning comes like:-                 
 react-dom.development.js:500 Warning: React does not recognize the `isOpen` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isopen` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in div (created by GalleryModal)
    in GalleryModal (created by Gallery)
    in div (created by Gallery)
    in Gallery

Comment: I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er9fx56n/ In your outer div component of GalleryModal you put an "isOpen" prop - but this simply not defined for the chosen div component (and actually it has no impact in your code, neither in function nor in style). If you get rid of it, the error will not show up anymore.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot grenzbotin ,Actually I have so many doubts but  if I put all these doubts in one word I can make individual component easily but I am facing problem to connect these all. Just suppose I created the rotation logic like https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/tk2e4du8/4/  but when I am adding this logic into the code its showing that rotation in not defined.So how can I do this and also and how can I understand to add components. I thank you alot we newbie need helper like you! you are great!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ayush88089/tk2e4du8/10/   I created this but what happens actually it is rotating the image which is in background instead of span image

Comment: Well, it goes a bit beyond the topic. But your problem is, that you apply the rotatation to all the GalleryImage components that got rendered (see line 100). But you only want to apply it to your image in the model component that renders the selected image (line 59). So you need to pass the current rotatation state to that modal like we did it with the selected image.

Comment: can you( @grenzbotin)please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778876/how-to-call-images-dynamically-in-ajax-using-react